# App doesn't appear in Launchpad

Tags: finder, applications, monterey, launchpad

I use Avidemux, which is a great lightweight app for simple video edits. I recently upgraded to version 2.8.0, and around the same time upgraded MacOS to Monterey 12.1. Suddenly, Avidemux is no longer appearing in Launchpad!

Here it is in the Applications folder:

[image: Avidemux in the Applications folder]

But a search in Launchpad turns up nothing:

[image: Avidemux not in Launchpad]

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the app - it launches from the Finder and works fine. So why doesn't it appear in Launchpad? And how can I fix it? It's pretty annoying to not be able to open it the way I open every other app.

Comment: Launch this line on Terminal ```rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db ; killall Dock``` https://osxdaily.com/2011/08/01/refresh-launchpad-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/

Comment: @LorisFoe Hey I looked at that article again and noticed that one-liner is for Lion. Later systems use [a different one](https://osxdaily.com/2015/05/05/reset-launchpad-layout-mac-os-x/): `defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock`. Worked for me! If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments simply launch this in Terminal

`defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock`

Answer (score 1):

Or, just drag the application onto the Launchpad icon. More details are available at [Mac apps not showing up in Launchpad? Here’s how to get them back](https://appletoolbox.com/mac-apps-not-showing-up-in-launchpad-heres-how-to-get-them-back/).